# Call a JSP page through javascript on button click

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, model-view-controller, buttonclick

I am currently working on an MVC program where I need to call the `home.jsp` page when the user logs in from the `login.jsp`. I have written the code for the login and home controllers that render the views. But am not sure how to call the controllers' request mapping through my `custom.js` javascript file that I have under my resources.

**custom.js**

```
document.getElementById('login_btn').addEventListener("click", function() {
    authorizationCheck();
}, false);


function authorizationCheck()
{
    var username = document.getElementById('username_txt').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password_txt').value;

    if(username == "admin" && password == "123")
    {
       //code to load the home.jsp
    }
}
```

**HomeController.java**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Locale locale, Model model) {   
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        return "home";
    }
}
```

I am quite new to this framework. So any suggestions on how to load a different jsp upon a button click will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Create a html form and submit your form in the authorizationCheck method.

Comment: You can use `window.location="home.jsp"` in you JS code to redirect to another page.

Comment: Code to submit the form may be as simple as document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

Comment: @dsp_user Could you kindly provide a tiny example, maybe a code snippet? Thanks in advance

Comment: **Please, go back and start over!** This is a terrible approach to verify a login in clear text on the client. For a basic approach: Build a regular web form, POST the login data, verify and redirect **on the server-side**, if the login data is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form could be as simple as (part of JSP)

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="http://localhost/your_app_root/check_credentials.jsp">
<input id="username-txt" name = "username" type="text" value="some_username">
<input id="password-txt" name = "password" type="text" value="some_password">
<input type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

In JS

```
 function authorizationCheck()
    {
   //do some processing if necessary (you can encrypt username/psw but   this   is only slightly more secure)       
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
```

In your controller (is it Spring) you will retrieve the username and password as `@RequestParam` parameters.

In plain JSP (JSP/servlet), you'd use `request.getParameter("username")` and `request.getParameter("password")` respectively.

Comment: Thanks. This works when I modify it to a `get` instead of a `post`.

Comment: Done. Thanks. 

Answer (score 1):

You can see a simple example here:
https://dzone.com/articles/spring-mvc-example-for-user-registration-and-login-1

If you only want show home page after checked in JS, you can use:

```
if(username == "admin" && password == "123")
{
    document.location.href = "home";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, It will navigate to spring controller and display desired page

```
if(username == "admin" && password == "123")
{
    document.location.href = "/home";
}
```

Comment: Is this calling the controller's method or directly invoking the view from the javascript?

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: Try this remove '/' before home
document.location.href = "home";